# "IndexError: list index out of range" for TableStyle in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to create a simpel table and assign a TableStyle to it:

```
data= [[Logo, 'Qualitycontrol ( QMH )\nForms', '', getTimeStamp(False)],
["tank", "cleaning", '', 'Revision: '+revisionsNumber]]
topHeaderTable=Table(data, colWidths="*")
#header formatting
topHeaderTable.setStyle(TableStyle([('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(4,1),'CENTER'), 
    ('SPAN',(1,0),(2,0)), 
    ('SPAN',(1,1),(2,1))]))
elements.append(topHeaderTable)
elements.append(linebreak)
```

This approach was running fine on my other device but I'm now getting this error:

```
line 73, in getDefaultTemplate
    topHeaderTable.setStyle(TableStyle([('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
line 1031, in setStyle
    self._addCommand(cmd)
line 1097, in _addCommand
    _setCellStyle(self._cellStyles, i, j, op, values)
line 1671, in _setCellStyle
    new = cellStyles[i][j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: on your other device?
maybe the python versions are not the same?

Comment: Both use Python 3.8.5 and the same reportlab version

Comment: Found the error in line 7: ('ALIGN',(0,0),(4,1),'CENTER')  changed to ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER') . Apparently my other installation ignored that i only have 2 rows instead of 4

Answer (score 0):

It says list index out of range thus there is some problem with looping I believe.
Try checking your 'data' variable values if they are less than the required.